# How to be sure I always call remove on a view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a region on the page, let's say given by:

```
<div id="region1"></div>
<div id="region2"></div>
```

I have several views in the app. At any one time, any one of them may be rendered into `#region1`. Then, another one is rendered.

I don't want to just call `$('#region1').html('')` to get rid of the html from the last view in the app region. I want to call `.remove()` on the being discarded view. But I don't know which one it is.

What is the best pattern for dealing with this situation? Should I be tracking the "active" view in something in my application code and calling `remove` on that?

I.e. my application has something like:

```
//update this every time a view is rendered into region1
app.regions.region1.currentView = viewA ;
```

then when I render another view into `region1`, I first call:

```
app.regions.regions1.currentView.remove()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to share a `div` and keep track of the view being rendered is to manage the app layout with a view.

Here's a simple layout view taken from [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40567785/1218980). Take a look at `setContent` where the view is swapped with the new one, and `remove` is called on the old one, if any.

```
var Layout = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body' // just for the simple example, let's put this as the body.

    // This avoids repeating selector strings everywhere in the view code.
    // If you change a class name in the template, change it only once here.
    regions: {
        header: '.header',
        content: '.content',
        sidebar: '.sidebar'
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
        var regions = this.regions;

        // I like to "namespace" my sub-views into an object.
        // That way, you still can access them by name, but you can also
        // loop on the sub-views.
        this.views = {
            sidebar: new SideBar({ el: regions.sidebar }),
            header: new Header({ el: regions.header }),
        };

        this.$content = this.$(regions.content);
    },

    render: function() {
        _.invoke(this.views, 'render');
        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Set the content to a view.
     * @param {Backbone.View} view to replace the content with.
     */
    setContent: function(view) {
        var views = this.views,
            content = views.content;
        if (content !== view) {
            if (content) content.remove();
            views.content = content = view;
            this.$content.html(content.render().el);
        }
    },
});
```

Then use it:

```
var layout = new Layout(),
    homepage = new HomePage();
layout.render()
    .setContent(homepage);

// ...later, changing the content view
layout.setContent(newView); // as simple as this
```

Comment: So. My logic is the same but (again) you have shown me how to do this nicely. I hadn't thought about the concept of a layout view.

Comment: @JustinWyllie With Backbone, everything is a component (a view), and the whole app is a complex component made from all other simpler components. From a simple input field component to the layout component. Once you stick to this concept, Backbone development becomes a lot less tedious.