# One view for 2 or more pages (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have two pages. One of them is dashboard with a lot of functionality. The second page is shared dashboard - the simple version of the first page.
The dashboard contains the view of the database (it can contain much other info, but the problem with this one). You can click on the filter button and modal window will be opened. So, simple version of the dashboard doesn't have this possibility. I'd like to add it, but I don't want to copy+past code from the full version of the dashboard because the code of this part is about two thousand lines. I'll add some primitive code example:

```
DashboardView = SomeAnotherView.extend({
initialize: function() {...},
events: {...} // huge objects of jQuery events,
render: function () {...},
... // 2k lines of functions for events
});
```

How can I use this View on another page? I tried to call a function from this view:

```
DashboardView.prototype.filterClicked(event);
```

But in this case event.curentTarget is null (it is necessary for this function), I also tried to send "this" to get the context, but it was failed.
**Is there a possibility in Backbone.js to use one *View* for 2+ pages without any huge copy/past code?**

Comment: Backbone views should be loosely coupled components. So you could have a view for a table view, for the page that as the table in it, for the simple menu, and for the dashboard which only uses the other views as parts of itself.

Comment: I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40567785/1218980) which explains a simple layout concept with a router example.

Comment: Also, the question, as it stands now, is [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). You're basically asking how to use Backbone to build a single-page app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally if you have a simple version and full version of a view, you should have a "base view" (simple one) and the full version should extend the base view.

It'll look something like:

```
var SimpleDashbard = Backbone.view.extend({});
var Dashboard = SimpleDashbard.extend({});
```

In this way Dashboard will have access to the methods from `SimpleDashbard`.

Your situation sounds like you need to use a method from extended view in base view. Which is not a good idea. Ideally if it's shared you should move it to the base view/extract it into a utility method or service, and of course this involve re-writing this method to be reusable

Answer (score -1):

If you have views that share a large amount of functionality, you could consider using the same View type, but opening it up to some configuration when instancing.  For example:

```
var DashboardView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.allowFunctionX = (options && options.allowFunctionX);
        this.allowFunctionY = (options && options.allowFunctionY);
    },
    // etc
    functionX: function() {
        if (!this.allowFunctionX) { return; }
        // do the function...
    },
    functionY: function() {
        if (!this.allowFunctionY) { return; }
        // do the function...
    },
});
```

Then on one page:

```
var firstDashView = new DashboardView({allowFunctionX: true});
```

and on another page:

```
var secondDashView = new DashboardView({allowFunctionY: true});
```

This may become not worth it if the functionality diverges too much (and there are likely better ways to configure than passing in a long list of booleans!). If your requirements are significantly different on your two pages, I feel like duplicating the code they both need is not a major sin.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it. It isn't my project, I just start learning Backbone and got the problem.